# Alien Isolation DLC not appearing on Play Game list

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, alien-isolation

So I have purchased the Alien Isolation Collection that includes all the DLC, and I have installed everything but I can't see the option to access any of it apart from Survival Mode with the one mission.

I have checked on my notifications and downloads and I can't find any logs about the time/date of installing the DLC. The only thing i can find is the base game. I also went on the PS Store to individually take a look at the DLC, but it says 'Installed'.

Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Look at the library. Everything purchased will be listed there.